# Working with undefined variables in Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm setting up a Mongo script to take variables by --eval, like so:

```
mongo mydb myscript.js --eval "parameter = 'value'"
```

However, I want the script to still work without requiring the `--eval`.

If this were browser-based JS, I'd just do a `var internalParameter = window.parameter || null` sort of thing to get around the ReferenceError thrown by checking for an undefined variable, but `mongo` doesn't have `window`. Is it possible to access variables through the global object in Mongo scripting, or do I just have to wrap this in a try/catch?

Comment: The global object (defined as `window` in browsers) can commonly be accessed as `this` in the global scope, or [(as of ES 2020)](https://dev.to/twostepdevelopers/what-is-globalthis-es2020-new-features-30oc) `globalThis` in lower scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that I've learned a little more about common JavaScript idioms, I know you can also do:

```
var internalParameter = typeof parameter == "undefined" ? null : parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

In myscript.js you can do:

```js
var parameter = parameter || null;
```

If `parameter` is passed in via the `--eval` it will have that value, otherwise it will be `null`.

**UPDATE**

To do it without defining the input variable you can use the fact that `this` refers to the global object in the shell and do:

```
var internalParameter = this.parameter || null;
```

Comment: No you can't. If `parameter` is undefined, referencing it causes a ReferenceError.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley It worked fine when I tried it with the 2.2.2 mongo shell.  If `parameter` is undefined, the `var parameter` part of the statement defines it prior to the rest of statement being evaluated.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is one possible workaround- if you do a `var parameter = parameter || null` first, it works (probably because the variable declaration counts in the assignment). I'm still curious if there's a way to do it without defining the input variable (ie `var differentParameterName = parameter || null`).

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Added alternative to do it without defining the input var.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your script could set a default like this:

```
var parameter = parameter || 'default';
print('parameter = ' + parameter);
```

And then it would be possible to pass parameters or leave the default:

```
% mongo script.js                                           
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
parameter = default

% mongo script.js --eval "var parameter = 'something else';"
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
parameter = something else
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve a similar problem:

```
function set_param(name, default_val)
{
    if (typeof this[name] === "undefined")
        this[name] = default_val;
}

set_param("DAYS_BACK", 180);
set_param("BATCH_SIZE", 1000);
```

Now if either of the parameters is given with an `--eval` argument, MongoDB shell will use what was provided. Otherwise it will use the default supplied by the second argument to `set_param()`. The variables whose names were given as the first argument to `set_param()` are safe to use once `set_param()` is executed regardless of the use of `--eval`.